Workaround for mapping apex domain names to Cloudfront distributions
I have a domain at an external provider, which I don't want to transfer into AWS, but would like to point it to an existing Cloudfront distribution. Subdomains, including www work with CNAME, but the example.com part -- the apex domain -- doesn't and it requries A or AAAA addresses at that provider (no ALIAS/CNAME).
I know this is a known issue in AWS, but I wonder if there is any workaround that I could use. For example Vercel is also hosted on AWS, they still use CNAME aliases for subdomains (cname.vercel-dns.com), but for the apex they do provide static, anycast IP addresses using the Global Accelerator service.
Would it be possible to create an example.com -> GA IP -> API GW? -> Cloudfront style workaround, which could work with multiple domains and distributions in a sane way?

What is your canonical domain for SEO? If it is the subdomain then you really just need a server that constantly returns a 301 redirect to the subdomain. If your DNS provider is GoDaddy you can just setup a redirect for the apex.
Anyway you could simply do this:
www -> GA -> ALB
And then add a bunch fo 301 redirect rules on the ALB. I feel your pain... I just migrated the DNS. But god almighty the VOIP and mail records that stack up over time...sheesh

Yeah, I know this workaround. The domain provider allows HTTP redirects (and yes it could be done from AWS itself, too), but I would really like to not do it.
I already had to add Cloudfront Edge functions just to get to the index.html in each folder, so it would be great to avoid other redirection magic. And since I am already paying for AWS it would be nice if they would provide meaningful solutions to this.
I don't understand why it would be impossible to really just use the apex domain for a simple static site.

My question regarding SEO was because in my case, even though I use Route53, I still return a 301 redirect for any requests to the apex domain from a Cloudfront Edge function...  Every now and then I see a company actually use the apex as a canonical but I advise against it.
